# Event triggered when the video stream is started, with getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, getusermedia, mediadevices

I'm using the ZXing JS barcode scanner library https://github.com/zxing-js/library/ with a video stream input (webcam or phone camera), as detailed in the following code.

**In general, how to add an event listener to a `<video>` to do an action when a video stream has just started?** (a video using the [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) video stream API, started from ZXing's `decodeFromInputVideoDevice`)?

```js
const codeReader = new ZXing.BrowserQRCodeReader();

codeReader
  .decodeFromInputVideoDevice(undefined, 'video')  // uses the default input
  .then(result => console.log(result.text))  // this happens when the barcode is found / recognized
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@zxing/library@0.15.2/umd/index.min.js"></script>
<video id="video"></video>
```

Note: for now I'm using `setTimeout(..., 2000)` when the user has clicked on the button to start the video, but obviously this fails in the case there is a dialog box "Do you want to allow this website to use the camera device?", then 2 seconds is not enough. A listener on event "VideoHasJustStarted" would be better.

**Edit:**
[Here is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6m0wuk7/) showing the issue: not working with various events: `started`, `devicechange`.

Comment: I am guessing a stream 'starts' when a video is playing? If so, have you tried the `video.addEventListener('playing', function() {})` listener? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playing_event

Comment: @Oliver, I'm not "playing" a video, I'm using the video stream capture (from webcam or smartphone camera). Does this apply here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to detect if a video is playing, or can be played, using event listeners:

```
let video = document.querySelector('video');

// Video has been started/unpaused
video.addEventListener('play', function() {
    ...
})

// Video has resumed play/started/unpaused/finished buffering/finished seeking, etc
video.addEventListener('playing', function() {
    ...
})

// Video can start playing (but might not be playing)
video.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
    ...
})

// Video can be played without buffering (but might not be playing)
video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
    ...
})
```

Most similar to `VideoHasJustStarted` is probably `playing`. But depending on how you want to execute your function, one of the above methods should fit your needs.

More info on video events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

## Example

```js
// Get video
var video = document.querySelector('video');

// Add event listener to monitor events
video.addEventListener('playing', () => {
  console.log('Video is now streaming!')
});

// Add stream
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true
  })
  .then(function(stream) {
    var videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();

    stream.onremovetrack = function() {
      console.log('Stream ended');
    };
    window.stream = stream;
    video.srcObject = stream;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {

    console.log(error);
  });
```

```html
<video id="video" autoplay muted></video>
```

Tested on Firefox on laptop - permission is requested to use webcam and the `console.log` fires when the video starts. As StackOverflow blocks the above from running inline, [link to working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohepworthbell/azcspxow)

Comment: I'm not "playing" a video (e.g. a MP4 video), but I'm using the realtime video stream capture (from webcam or smartphone camera). Does `playing` apply in this case?

Comment: Looking at the API for `getUserMedia`, it accepts a `loadedmetadata` event to load, and uses the `play()` callback to begin a stream, which are both standard for the html5 video API, so it should accept other standard API events in response too (i.e. `play` and `playing`)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Examples

Comment: On the off-chance the API does differ, please see latest edit @Basj

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle, it does not seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/j6m0wuk7/ (none of the 2 events seem to be fired).

Comment: Yeah sorry I checked and my first answer was right - https://jsfiddle.net/ohepworthbell/azcspxow

Comment: Thanks, it works! (Bounty can only be awarded after 24 hours, so I'll do it later)